# git push is not working in bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I've git repository in bitbucket. In my local repository i made a new branch *fixes*.I need to push the commits to remote bitbucket repo.

I pushed using the command

> git push github master

I get the message Everything up to-date.But am not able to see those commits in remote repo.

With the following command

> git remote show github

I get,

```
remote github   
    Fetch URL: https://me@bitbucket.org/me/sample.git   
    Push  URL:https://me@bitbucket.org/me/sample.git   
    HEAD branch: master 
    Remote branch:
       master tracked   
    Local ref configured for 'git push':
       master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Why is it happening so? whether i need to create new branch in remote repository too to be connected with my local repo branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only using `push` on the branch called `master` when you run this command:

```
git push github master
```

Is there any particular reason why you've named the bitbucket 'remote' as `github`? That's really confusing when reading it.

Run this:

```
git push github fixes
```

Assuming that you've still got your `bitbucket` remote named as `github`.

Comment: No reason.just named it as 'github'.Thanks!